# Call foreign key in foreign key on PHP

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I'm confused, because of this 3 tables, can i call a foreign key in another foreign key?

I got 3 tables, `Component`, `PC`, and `Processor`.

```
  ALTER TABLE `component` (
      `componentID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `Name_component` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `processorIDFK` int(10) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`componentID`),
       UNIQUE KEY `Processor` (`processorId`),
       CONSTRAINT processor_IDFK FOREIGN KEY (`processorIDFK`) REFERENCES processor(`processorID`)   
       );

 ALTER TABLE `PC` (
      `PCID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name_PC` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `componentIDFK` int(10) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`PCID`),
      UNIQUE KEY `component` (`componentId`),
      CONSTRAINT component_IDFK FOREIGN KEY (`componentIDFK`) REFERENCES component(`componentId`)
      );

 CREATE TABLE `processor` (
     `processorId` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `processor_Name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`processorId`)
      );
```

Can i call/use `SELECT` for processor_name in PC table? with this table relationship?

Comment: Do you mean [`JOIN`s](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)? They enable you to `SELECT` columns from other tables as well.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow yeah, i got that from the answer. and how to use Insert with that join? or anything else?

Comment: sorry, I came from review and didn't see the answer from there. I'm not sure why you would want to `INSERT` with `JOIN`, but AFAIK you can't and have to write one `INSERT` per table.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow i just want to use `SELECT` and `INSERT`, if `SELECT` use `JOIN` and `INSERT` just use `INSERT`?, selecting and inserting data from `Foreignkey` to `Foreignkey`. This is why im confused how to do it.

Comment: Yes, exactly. See the comment on Huberts answer, he explains how to do it.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow yeah, now im trying the code what he said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

The thing you need to do is to join your tables.

```
SELECT processor_Name FROM PC t1 
INNER JOIN component t2 ON t1.componentIDFK=t2.componentID 
INNER JOIN processor t3 ON t3.processorId=t2.processorIDFK
```

Comment: and how about the insert? it using join too?

Comment: You need to `INSERT` each row by single query. To do this you need to begin from the end of join chain. I mean, first you need to add row to processor table, then you will reach `processorId` and then you can create component and add this as foreign key. At the end you create processor and pass `componentId` when inserting. To sum up, to create such combination you need to do 3 inserts. Order of inserts is important, because otherwise you will get mysql errors about missing or incorrect foreign key. If you are scared about consistency you should use database transaction.

Comment: transaction? using rollback?

Comment: It's not necessary at all, but it's worth of knowing that some inserts can fail and then your data will be not consistent. Thus, in your code you should surround your insert with transaction and if any error occurs you should rollback your changes. Otherwise you should commit your changes, to make them persistent in database.

Comment: just make 1 transaction to multiple insert or 1 trasaction for 1 insert?

Comment: Within transaction you usually do multiple inserts. You can do whatever you want inside transaction, until you don't commit your changes, they are only visible inside your transaction. I suggest you using transaction to ensure that data you insert are 100% consistent.

Comment: i see, okay ill try to learn to use transaction. Thanks for your help sir.